# MySQL Aurora database returns True value in response for fields which has null value

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-aurora-serverless

While fetching data from MySQL Aurora database using boto, it always returning **True** value for the fields in table which does not contain any value or which contains NULL value.

```
rds_client = boto3.client("rds-data")

emp_id_param = {
             "name": "emp_id",
             "value": {"longValue": 123}
           }

sql = "select * from employee where employee_id = :emp_id"

# Querying the data
result_set = rds_client.execute_statement(
    resourceArn=cluster_arn,
    includeResultMetadata=True,
    secretArn=secret_arn,
    database=db_name,
    sql=sql,
    parameters=[emp_id_param],
)
```

After executing this query, I am always getting "true" values for fields which has not data stored.
Does any one has any idea how can I get "null" value as response instead of "true" value.

Comment: Would it help us understand if you showed us the query you are executing

Comment: yes..added sample query. its happening with any select query